# Reactivar pregunta vieja

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Hice una pregunta que nadie me contestó quizá por la hora y se fue para abajo, quisiera volver a reactivarla o que vuelva a aparecer, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Ediatarla y agregar detalles relevantes a la misma, eso la colocará al inicio del listado de preguntas de nuevo, trata de hacerla llamativa leyendo [ask]

Comment: Como comenta @BetaM considera realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] de esta forma la comunidad puede ayudarte de mejor forma, por ejemplo en esta pregunta que realizas, porque no agregas detalles de que pregunta fue? ,saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Las preguntas se pueden ordenar como:

- Activo
- Con recompensa
- Popular
- Semana
- Mes

Si tú pregunta no tiene una recompensa ofertada y no tiene ediciones posteriores al momento de su publicación va a ir quedando abajo en el listado de preguntas mientras más dudas sean publicadas.

La ventaja que tenemos tanto en preguntas como respuestas es la posibilidad de editar las mismas para:

- Agregar información relevante
- Formatear código
- Explicar a mayor detalle
- Tal vez agregar etiquetas o quitarlas para ubicar de forma más efectiva a la misma

En fin toda aquella información que ayude a:

- Que la comunidad comprenda mejor tu duda
- Puedan reproducir tu escenario y visualizar el problema
- Comprendan cual es el resultado esperado
- Visualicen los errores que tienes al momento
- Etc.

En resumen si quieres lanzar al inicio de nuevo tu publicación, puedes: **editar para ampliarla**, considerar ofrecer una recompensa.

Conviene aclarar que las recompensas son de mínimo 50 puntos de tu reputación y funcionan cuando tienes en esta al menos [75 puntos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Los votos negativos

- No se deben entender sobre la persona sino sobre la publicación
- En estos casos puedes leer los posibles comentarios que te hayan dejado pues *tal vez hay cosas por mejorar*
- Si no te dejaron comentarios, entonces tu mismo *puedes evaluar tu pregunta* y mejorarla de ser necesario

Comment: De hecho me pusieron varios dislike en la pregunta y me bajaron puntos